# NoneType has no attribute 'json_string'

Tags: python, json, quill

I'll keep this short because I haven't had great luck with posts in the past. I'm building a website that uses the quill text editor (unimportant) and saves the text to a database which can later be used to edit. Everything runs perfectly in my local hosted server when I run "python manage.py runserver". However when I run it on Heroku to host it online I get this error...

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://vast-river-12269.herokuapp.com/signup/new_search/posts/create/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json_string'
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_quill/forms.py, line 17, 
in 
prepare_value
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.13
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

It says no attribute json_string in NoneType which seems very generic. I also haven't worked with json in my project and I don't see it anywhere. I have however narrowed the problem down to one line of code. In my HTML I have a line calling a variable "{{ forms.content }}. This line is the problem and I t correlates to the bellow models.py file and forms.py file. They are attached below but I cant find any problem in there and it works on my local host so I don't understand.

What I want to know in this post.

- How to fix this problem
- Why this problem happened

models.py...

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django_quill.fields import QuillField


# Create your models here.


class QuillPost(models.Model):
    content = QuillField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pk']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('quill-post-detail', args=[self.pk])




class Text(models.Model):
    document = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.document

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    pass


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()

class Search(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    search = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.search)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Searches'
```

forms.py...

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser
from .models import Text
from django_quill.forms import QuillFormField
from .models import QuillPost


class QuillForm(forms.Form):
    quill = QuillFormField()



class QuillFieldForm(forms.Form):
    content = QuillFormField()

    def save(self):
        return QuillPost.objects.create(content=self.cleaned_data['content'])


class QuillPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = QuillPost
        fields = ['content']
```

sorry for the long post but I really need help.

Comment: How much digging have you done?  The problem occurs in `QuillFormField.prepare_value`.  It expects to receive a JSON string as its second parameter.  You have two uses of that, but I don't see that `QuillForm` is used anywhere.  You have created a very confusing application here, with multiple overloads of Quill and content.  I don't know how you will chase this down.

Comment: I have done a lot of research but maybe I am too new to json to completely comprehend it. I have continued to do a lot of work on it. There is more to my website than what I posted so some of the above code is for other aspects of it. I'm sorry if that confused anyone. I can answer any questions anyone has if they need more information. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why it works on my localhost but no ton Heroku.